# how to find path from where current binary running?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, ps, binaries

After somewhere searching finally not getting what i want.

I am working on some embedded board with linux system. And many users access it by `telnet`.So each user suppose copy some binary somewhere and executed like `./binary`.So i can see this process running by simply `ps` command but from where it's running i don't know.

somewhere found that, use `which` command but as per my understanding(if i am not wrong) `which` command find only path of that binary whether it's currently executing or not.

And what if multiple users copied same binary in different path?

Also looked another solution use `readlink` but limited `busybox binary` supported in my target board. So `readlink` is not there.

One another solution like

`file /proc/"proess id"/exe` but here `file`  command not present because of custome linux in my board which contain only limited functionality and binary.

So any other solution is there?

Comment: You may use `ls -l` and extract a component after `->`

Comment: To close voter : it is not about a tool. I would rather close it as off topic, for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user3159253 `readlink` would be better than parsing `ls` output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ls -l /proc/"proess id"/exe`. `ls` utility from GNU coreutils shows links with `-l` option, but I don't have exact information about `ls` from `busybox`.